# using form `setPristine` throws error

Tags: angularjs

I am getting error while i use the setPristine with  my form.
error is:

[Error message](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24setPristineProvider%20%3C-%20%24setPristine%20%3C-%20mainController)

```
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24setPristineProvider%20%3C-%20%24setPristine%20%3C-%20mainController
```

my controller:

```
"use strict";

var mainController = ['$scope', '$route', '$location', "$document", "$timeout", "modalService", "$setPristine",
 function ($scope, $route, $location, $document, $timeout, modalService, $setPristine) {

    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (oldVal !== newVal) {
            $scope.routeClassName = $route.current.className;
        }
    });

    //config actions

    $scope.changePasswrod = function ( data ) {

        console.log( "change password called", data ); //i am getting data here.
        $scope.formResetPassword.$setPristine();


    }

}];

angular
    .module('tcpApp')
    .controller('mainController', mainController);
```

my form :

```
<form ng-submit="changePasswrod( changePass )" class="configForm resetPassword" name="formResetPassword" novalidate>
    <a ng-click='hideModal()' class="configPopClose" ng-href=""><img src="images/configCloaseIcon.png" alt=""></a>
    <h2>Change Password</h2>
    <span class="indication"> * Indicates require fields</span>
    <label for="userId" class="configUserId">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            name="userId" 
            ng-model="changePass.userId" 
            placeholder="User Id" 
            required > <sup>*</sup>
    </label>
    <span class="errorWrap">
        <span 
            ng-show="formResetPassword.userId.$dirty && 
            formResetPassword.userId.$invalid" 
            class="error">
                User Name Required
        </span>
    </span>
    <label for="oldPassword" class="configOldPass">
        <input type="password" 
            name="oldPassword" 
            placeholder="Old Password" 
            ng-model="changePass.oldPassword" 
            ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+$/"
            required > <sup>*</sup>
    </label>
    <span class="errorWrap">
        <span 
            ng-show="formResetPassword.oldPassword.$dirty && 
            formResetPassword.oldPassword.$invalid" 
            class="error">
                Please provide the old password
        </span>
    </span>
    <label for="newPassword" class="configNewPass">
        <input 
            type="password" 
            name="newPassword" 
            placeholder="New Password" 
            ng-model="changePass.newPassword"
            ng-pattern="/^[^\s]+$/"
            required > <sup>*</sup> 
    </label>
    <span class="errorWrap">
        <span 
            ng-show="formResetPassword.newPassword.$dirty && formResetPassword.newPassword.$invalid"
            class="error">
                Please provide new Password
        </span>
    </span>
    <label for="reEnterNewPassword" class="configReEnter">
        <input 
            type="password" 
            name="newPasswordConf" 
            placeholder="Re-Enter New Password" 
            ng-model="changePass.newPasswordConf" 
            required > <sup>*</sup> 
    </label>
    <span class="errorWrap">
        <span 
            ng-show="formResetPassword.newPasswordConf.$dirty && 
            (changePass.newPassword != changePass.newPasswordConf || !formResetPassword.newPasswordConf.$valid)" 
            class="error">
                Password Not Matching;
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="configBtnHolder">
        <button 
            class="applyBtn configBtn" 
            type="submit" 
            id="stayChangePass" 
            ng-disabled="formResetPassword.$invalid"
            >
                Stay on Dashboard
        </button>
        <button 
            class="cancelBtn configBtn" 
            type="submit" 
            id="exitChangePass"
            ng-disabled="formResetPassword.$invalid">
                Exit Dashboard
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to inject `$setPristine` in your controller. Remove it from the dependency injection list and it should work fine.

Comment: After I remove, I am getting this eroror `TypeError: Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined`

Comment: which means $scope.formResetPassword is not defined, that is, somehow your form isn't available in your controller's scope. Where does your form reside? Can your create a plunker?

Comment: here is my form html : `
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-class="routeClassName">

 <div class="wrapper">
  <div ng-class="pageClass" ng-view></div>
 </div>
 <config-popup></config-popup> //my form

 
<body>`

Comment: the code looks fine to be honest. You'll have to recreate the problem in a plunker.

Comment: I have added the controller right in the form, it works : `<form ng-controller="mainController" ng-submit="changePassword( changePass )" class="configForm resetPassword" name="formResetPassword" novalidate>` - technically is it wrong?

Comment: No, it looks fine to me.